# Unable to publish to Microsoft Azure API Apps (Preview)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net

I currently have Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 RC installed on my PC. With Azure 2.6 I can see the new Microsoft Azure API Apps (Preview) when publishing.

**Visual Studio 2013**

[image]

On 2015 I don't see the option

**Visual Studio 2015 RC Enterprise**

[image]

Yet it looks like I have everything installed correctly

[image]

Is there anything else I need to do to get the publish option for API Apps?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to azure management portal, download a publish profile for the api you wish to publish.
once downloaded, import the publish profile, it will automatically save the  profile for the next publish too.

Comment: That does work but I am still wondering why I am not getting the option in Publish Web.

Comment: I use studio 13 and honestly i dont  get the option for Azure Api Apps (preview). Has to be something related to allowed access to certain publish features in the azure management portal.